# Is GPGPU programming on Apple Silicon possible?

Tags: macos, opencl, gpgpu

I'm in the process of learning computer graphics and in particular the OpenCL, OpenGL and Vulkan libraries. Currently, I use those on a Windows 10 machine with an Nvidia graphics card.

Most of the development will stay on that machine, but I would like to buy myself a new MacBook Pro, which I will use for personal stuff like finances etc. and occasionally use it to also develop some of the GPGPU stuff.

My aim is for my code to be as cross-platform capable as possible since I'm also using OpenCL instead of e.g. CUDA.

Apple has since a while now replaced all of the processors in their computers with their own Apple Silicon chips. The MacBooks use the M-Series chips.

Is it possible to use those three libraries on the current Apple Silicon M-Series chips? And if not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: OpenGL and OpenCL are both deprecated, currently they still work, but noone knows when they will finally be removed. Vulkan has (natively) never worked on Mac. There is MoltenVK that emulates Vulkan on Metal. Summary: There is no fully supported and future proof GPU API anymore that supports all operating systems.

Comment: @BDL The Vulkan Portability Initiative pretty much covers that: 
 https://www.vulkan.org/porting  Sure, you have to use a translation layer on Mac, but the low level APIs are congruent enough that it doesn't really seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### OpenCL and OpenGL:

Available (they work) but deprecated (might stop working with future updates).
Apple encourages developers that use this APIs to [switch to Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/porting-your-macos-apps-to-apple-silicon) (more low level, similar to Vulkan) or other higher level libraries.

#### Vulkan

Not officially supported, MoltenVK can be used to translate Vulkan calls to Metal.

#### Native APIs

Apple pushes for everything GPU related to use Metal, but also provides other higher level frameworks for common tasks that make use of the GPU:

- CoreML: High level framework for machine learning tasks (from training models to using them in applications)
- SceneKit: High level framework for 2D and 3D graphics (more like a graphics engine)

To exploit CPU vectorization the Accelerate framework can be used.

Right now Apple does not seem to offer a framework for homogeneous computing on CPU and GPU exactly like OpenCL or CUDA.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any chance that MoltenVK will not work in the future like OpenGL/CL or would this be a safe & future-proof way for me to run my projects on an Apple Silicon machine? I will not use it to deploy any applications for MacOS, it would just be very helpful to code on another machine besides my home PC.

Comment: Using MoltenVK can be an OK way to develop Vulkan projects on a Mac as i think the Vulkan API and the Metal API will not have any major changes in the next few years (so MoltenVK should remain usable). But keep in mind that the API that MoltenVK exposes is a subset of the Vulkan API and as such more niche Vulkan features might not be available.

Comment: @baltermia Bear in mind that the MoltenVK library is implemented on top of Metal, using a software translation to map the Vulkan calls to their roughly equivalent Metal calls.  From the perspective of Apple, a MoltenVK app is just another Metal app, and in order to prevent the use of MoltenVK, Apple would need to modify Metal in a way that would potentially break other Metal apps, so it's unlikely to happen.